# Computing the mass of the cube subtracking the defects mass

Tags: java, servlets, math, 3d

I am using JavaEE and Servlets. I have a problem with understanding and making one class in my project. If anyone is able to give me some tips how can I do it, how should I start do it or give me some examples I will be very grateful.

I need to create (using Servlets), the component named `Cube`. Servlet input is defined by 3 parameters: a - determines the length of the side
cube located at the origin (resulting from the scaling unit cube by a) expressed in meters [m]. Cube is made of a material having a specific density, c expressed in [kg] / [m3]. 
The material defects are present which are of the spherical shape and density of the material g.

The results of the test material structure containing a description of the defects - each of which is stored in the form of a sphere with center equation
at the point **(x, y, z)** and the radius r are sent to the servlet in a further `GET` requests. 
The order of the parameters **x, y, z** and **y** in the request (Url) is arbitrary. 
Receiving the request `POST` parameters: a - determines the length of the side of the ankle, c - characterized by material density
the cube was made and g - characterizing the density of the material in the areas of defects means that the transferred data set.

Receipt by the servlet request `POST` marks the transition to the phase of data analysis and determination of the result. `POST` request http
shall refer determined by the actual weight of the component of the analyzed block of material. To solve the task used to be
**Monte Carlo** method, wherein the result should be determined to an accuracy of no less than 10^(-2).

The program is to be stored only in a single file containing the code of the servlet `Cube.java` implementing mechanism
the search for solutions. The program can not use any external libraries.
The result of the program should be well rounded and formatted number with a value equal to the sought bulk solids - no
formatting and return complete html pages.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to understand the logic behind. Why would you need something like this? Is this a 'homework' or a 'task'??. Any relation to this: [Volume with Monte Carlo method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29055003/volume-with-monte-carlo-method)

Comment: This is a task, related to a project for a game 3D.

Comment: Maybe first the most important question. How can I sent to the servlet parameters x,y,z,r in a FURTHER GET requests ?

Comment: I would say that servlets and HTTP are immaterial to the problem you're trying to solve.  Figure out how to calculate density for a cube with inclusions first; then expose it via HTTP.    Take a cube of side length L made of material with theoretical density rho and calculate its total theoretical mass M and volume L^3.    Calculate the volume of all inclusions.  Since they are empty you can assign them a density of zero.  Subtract that missing mass from theoretical total, divide by L^3, and you'll have the adjusted total mass and density.